# Multiple billings for one user in one day for Monthly Recurring (Drupal commerce)

Tags: 7, commerce

Our Monthly Recurring Billing has been working successfully for more than 1 year. However, there are two customers are charged multiple times on February 28, 2018, once an hour.  Other 3 customers (monthly recurring) are charged correctly on the same day.

The cron "commerce_recurring_cron" runs every hour, and created a new order of recurring billing for the same user.

```
ORDER NUMBER    UPDATED NAME    USER    TOTAL   ORDER STATUS
8181    February 28, 2018 - 6:43pm  J* C*   j*  $4.99   Completed
8182    February 28, 2018 - 7:09pm  J* C*   j*  $4.99   Completed
8184    February 28, 2018 - 8:09pm  J* C*   j*  $4.99   Completed
8186    February 28, 2018 - 9:11pm  J* C*   j*  $4.99   Completed
8188    February 28, 2018 - 10:11pm J* C*   j*  $4.99   Completed
8190    February 28, 2018 - 11:00pm J* C*   j*  $4.99   Completed
8192    March 1, 2018 - 12:00am J* C*   j*  $4.99   Completed
8183    February 28, 2018 - 8:09pm  L* L*   l*  $4.99   Completed
8185    February 28, 2018 - 9:11pm  L* L*   l*  $4.99   Completed
8187    February 28, 2018 - 10:11pm L* L*   l*  $4.99   Completed
8189    February 28, 2018 - 11:00pm L* L*   l*  $4.99   Completed
8191    March 1, 2018 - 12:00am L* L*   l*  $4.99   Completed
```

All above payments of orders are charge successfully in Authorize.net.

System: Drupal 7.56; Authorize.net Gate Way. 
Related modules: commerce 7.x-1.13, commerce_recurring 7.x-2.x-dev, commerce_order 7.x-1.11, commerce_payment 7.x-1.11, commerce_authnet 7.x-1.4, commerce_cardonfile 7.x-2.0-beta5+3-dev.

I have spent days on doing research,  and debugging the Drupal log and system log.  But I can't find any useful info. 
I cannot repeat the problem on our DEV site.

I will deeply appreciate it if someone knows some clues about it by chance.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Any feedback on this one?

Answer (score 0):

There is a fixed issue with Commerce Authorize.Net, discussed on https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_authnet/issues/2161989.

If your setup already incorporates that fix, then most probably it is hitting the issue [Duplicate queue items should not be created](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_license_billing/issues/2252369). Apply the patch in #6 and you should be fine.

Comment: Our module commerce_authnet 7.x-1.4 has already contained this patch which is for 7.x-1.1. 
<code>
return (isset($transaction->status)) ? $transaction->status : TRUE;
</code>

Our commerce functionality of Monthly Recurring Billing had been working good for more than a year (2017). This problem just happened on  February 28, 2018. It is also working good recently.

Comment: The provided answer addresses your situation and so it would be really nice of you if you could accept it. Please note users here spend their efforts to help you, so if provided answer was good enough to help you then you should accept it.